# for loop right-triangles not separating

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
base=int(input("Enter the triangle size: "))
for i in range(1, base + 1):
    print (('*' * i) + (' ' * (base - i)))
for i in range(1, base + 1)[::-1]:
    print (('*' * i) + (' ' * (base - i)))
for i in range(1, base + 1):
    print (' ' * (base - i) + ('*' * i))
for i in range(1, base + 1)[::-1]:
    print (' ' * (base - i) + ('*' * i))
```

The output looks like this:

```
Enter the triangle size: 4
*   
**  
*** 
****
****
*** 
**  
*   
   *
  **
 ***
****
****
 ***
  **
   *
>>>
```

But I need it to look like this:

```
Enter the triangle size: 4
*   
**  
*** 
****

****
*** 
**  
*   
   *
  **
 ***
****

****
 ***
  **
   *
>>>
```

I tried everything to create a new line after each for loop but it just outputted a mess. Is there any way I can tweak my program to allow for those spaces? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just added prints between triangles to reproduce the expected output. Is that what you want ?

```
base=int(input("Enter the triangle size: "))
for i in range(1, base + 1):
    print (('*' * i) + (' ' * (base - i)))
print()
for i in range(1, base + 1)[::-1]:
    print (('*' * i) + (' ' * (base - i)))
for i in range(1, base + 1):
    print (' ' * (base - i) + ('*' * i))
print()
for i in range(1, base + 1)[::-1]:
    print (' ' * (base - i) + ('*' * i))
```

Output:

```
Enter the triangle size: 4
*   
**  
*** 
****

****
*** 
**  
*   
   *
  **
 ***
****

****
 ***
  **
   *
```